# Erro ao criar Banco de Dados pelo Visual Studio 2015

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, visual-studio

Estou com problemas, quando tento criar um Banco de Dados pelo **Visual Studio** aparece essa mensagem:

[image: Como posso reslver isso]

Answer (score 0):

Conforme a própria mensagem de erro diz: você precisa ter o LocalDB ou SQL Server Express instalado e em execução no computador local, ou seja, na sua máquina. Acredito que você não tenha o(s) programa(s) instalado(s) e/ou em execução.

Para solucionar o problema faça o que a mensagem instrui, vá para o link fornecido na mensagem de erro, selecione Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools, e instale a versão mais recente.

Comment: Ok, vou tentar, muito obrigado.

Comment: Qualquer coisa pode me procurar pelos comentários que vamos encontrar uma solução =D

Answer (score 0):

Você também pode configurar seu banco de forma local através do web.config. Geralmente ao criar o projeto o arquivo web.config já vem pré-configurado, basta ajustar. Verifique se possui o seguinte trecho de código.

Exemplo:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="Nome do Banco" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Vidly-20170823094631.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Vidly-20170823094631;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Segue link da configuração do meu web.config onde está com o banco configurado.

[GitHub](https://github.com/AndreySchemel/TFD_ProgTecnologia/blob/master/ApplicationCrud/Web.config)